# Is there any database / or webservice or link where we can search for GS1 - 128 codes and find product information from different stores?

Tags: java, barcode, gs1-128

I am in search of some search engines or websites or Stores where i can search products using GS1 codes in java.
Carrefour in uae uses GS1 data barcodes. I would like to search products using GS1 -128 barcode values using java.

Is it possible? please provide me your input.

Answer (score 0):

There are no free implementations (as in $ or beer). ZXing has had a long outstanding feature request for this: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=583

Googling gives me several commercial offerings, some as low as $2,000 for a simple library.